# Foreach loop (laravel blade)

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I need help with a foreach loop in laravel. For some reason I need to have two rows instead of two tables (would have solved my problem) However, I have problems with it getting to work due to not knowing where to place my tags to get the right table structure.

Code:

```
<table class="minimalistBlack">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Etternavn</th>
            <th>Navn</th>
            <th>Posthylle</th>
            <th>X</th>
            <th>Etternavn</th>
            <th>Navn</th>
            <th>Posthylle</th>

        </tr>
    @foreach ($data as $mailbox)
        <td>{{ $mailbox->last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $mailbox->first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $mailbox->row }}{{ $mailbox->number }}</td>
        <td></td>

    @endforeach
    @foreach ($data2 as $mailbox)
        <td>{{ $mailbox->last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $mailbox->first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $mailbox->row }}{{ $mailbox->number }}</td>
    @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I combine the two foreach loops and and get the right table structure?

Comment: use `array_merge()` function in your controller as `$d = array_merge($data, $data2);`  and in your view `@foreach($d as $data)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Put everything inside the same foreach!

Comment: Coult you please provide an example? i have tried? The thing is that i have split the original array into two for exactly this, because rows cannot exceed 72 rows before starting on the next row.

Answer (score 1):

to achieve just that result you could do

```
foreach (array_combine($courses, $sections) as $course => $section)
```

but that only works for two arrays

or u can use two table and make feel as single table

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<table class="table table-striped">
 @foreach ($data as $mailbox)
  <td>{{ $mailbox->last_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $mailbox->first_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $mailbox->row }}{{ $mailbox->number }}</td>
  <td></td>

 @endforeach
</table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<table class="table table-striped">
 @foreach ($data as $mailbox)
  <td>{{ $mailbox->last_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $mailbox->first_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $mailbox->row }}{{ $mailbox->number }}</td>
  <td></td>

 @endforeach
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot use two tables because of my PDF exporter not supporting bootstrap. :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `$data` and `$data2` variables are Laravel collection instances, you can simply use `$data = $data->concat($data2)`. Now `$data` will contain data of both variables. For a simple array, you can use `$data += $data2;`. This will merge `$data` & `$data2` to `$data`. Then you can simply use:

```
...
@foreach ($data as $mailbox)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $mailbox->last_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $mailbox->first_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $mailbox->row }}{{ $mailbox->number }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the code behind, maybe this helps you understand https://pastebin.com/Qac45cEx . Thank's for quick reply, do you know what i am trying to do? :) (Row's should not exceed 72 rows, before starting on the next)

Comment: In this case simply use ` return view('pdf.mailbox', ['data' => $take->concat($chunck)]);` and then only use `$data` in your blade view.

Comment: It combined it, but rows exceeded 72.  Should i post a screenshot explaining what i want to archieve?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/28d4d64c65eb5c1e91df1523154efa4e - This is what i am trying to archieve, when the counter hits 36* rows it starts printing on the other side of the table.

Comment: Do you know? :)

Answer (score 0):

User array_merge function in controller like this

```
$array1 = array("john","ny");
$array2 = array("mitchel","ny");
$result = array_merge($a1,$a2);
```

Answer (score 0):

if $data and $data2 have one, one row you can try like this.

```
@foreach ($data as $mailbox)
<tr>
<td>{{ $mailbox->last_name }}</td>
<td>{{ $mailbox->first_name }}</td>
<td>{{ $mailbox->row }}{{ $mailbox->number }}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@foreach ($data2 as $mailbox)
<tr>
<td>{{ $mailbox->last_name }}</td>
<td>{{ $mailbox->first_name }}</td>
<td>{{ $mailbox->row }}{{ $mailbox->number }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```